# Keras image augmentation for images with two channels

Tags: keras

I performed data augmentation for images with two channels. My data set is formatted in the shape of `(image_Numbers, image_height, image_weights, image_channels)`, where `image_channels = 2`.

In performing data augmentation using `datagen` (created by `ImageDataGenerator`), a userwarining message is generated:

```
UserWarning: NumpyArrayIterator is set to use the data format convention     
"channels_last" (channels on axis 3), 
i.e. expected either 1, 3 or 4 channels on axis 3. 
However, it was passed an array with shape (1, 150, 150, 2) (2 channels).
```

Does the warning imply the data augmentation was unsuccessful? Was it only performed for one channel images? If so, how to perform data augmentation for two-channels of images (not one channel this time and then concatenation)?

Answer (score 2):

It means they don't expect two channel images. It's non standard.

The standard images are:

- 1 channel: grayscale
- 3 channels: RGB
- 4 channels: RGBA

Since it's a warning, we don't really know what's going on.

Check the outputs of this generator yourself.

```
x, y = theGenerator[someIndex]
```

Plot `x[0]` and others.

In case the generated images aren't good, you can do the augmentations yourself using a python generator or a custom `keras.utils.Sequence`.